Persistent PID Issue with npm run dev Causing 'Connection Reset' Error
Hi I'm encountering a recurring issue with my project setup vite 5173 dev mode. Every time I run npm run dev, I face the following error in my browser:
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.

I discovered that this problem is related to an existing PID that I need to terminate manually each time before running the command. Here’s what I do to solve the issue temporarily:

    Run netstat -ano | findstr :5173
    Identify the PID, which in this case is 5220
    Terminate the PID using taskkill /PID 5220 /F

After terminating the PID, I run npm run dev again, and it works fine in the browser.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can permanently fix this issue so that I don't have to manually kill the PID every time?

Try inputing q Enter in the terminal to stop Vite when you want to stop the dev server
